# Posts are returning as many times a comment exists. How can I fix this?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, lumen

I'm working with lumen and Vuejs and left-joined my 'likes' and 'comments' table with my posts table. There are no problems with the likes, it's working fine.
But when I join the comments table, the posts are returned as many times a comment exists.

```
 if($request->limit == NULL){
        $request->limit = 4;
      }

      $user_name= $request->username;
      $post_id = $request->id;

      $user = User::where('username', $user_name)->first();

      $post_query = Posts::leftJoin('likes', 'posts.id', '=', 'likes.post_id')
                   ->leftJoin('comments', 'posts.id', '=', 'comments.post_id')
                      ->selectRaw('posts.*, count(likes.post_id) as likes')
                   ->selectRaw('posts.*, comments.comment as comment')
                      ->where('posts.user_id', $user->id)
                      ->groupBy('posts.id')
                   ->groupBy('comments.id')
                      ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                      ->limit($request->limit)
                      ->get();

      return response()->json($post_query);
```

My output with the code is:

```
{
    "id": 844,
    "user_id": 221,
    "content": "Das ist mein aller erster Post :) ",
    "created_at": "2019-07-01 09:09:00",
    "updated_at": "2019-07-01 09:09:00",
    "likes": 1,
    "comment": "Das ist der zweite Kommentar"
},
{
    "id": 844,
    "user_id": 221,
    "content": "Das ist mein aller erster Post :) ",
    "created_at": "2019-07-01 09:09:00",
    "updated_at": "2019-07-01 09:09:00",
    "likes": 1,
    "comment": "das ist der dritte :) "
}
```

but what I try to do is:

```
{
    "id": 844,
    "user_id": 221,
    "content": "Das ist mein aller erster Post :) ",
    "created_at": "2019-07-01 09:09:00",
    "updated_at": "2019-07-01 09:09:00",
    "likes": 1,
    "comments": {
      {
        'username' : 'test',
        'comment' : "Das ist der zweite Kommentar",
        'created_at': 12312312
      },
      {
        'username' : 'test',
        'comment' : "Das ist der dritte :)",
        'created_at': 12312312
      }
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas how I can do it?

Comment: Do you have the relationships of those models defined in Laravel?

Comment: That's actually normal SQL behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of Eloquent with the [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) defined:

**Post.php**

```
class Post extends Model {

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Like::class);
    }
}
```

Then in your query:

```
$posts = Post
             ::with('comments') // Eager loading the 'comments' relationship
             ->withCount('likes') // Attaching a 'likes_count' to every Post object
             ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
             ->limit($request->limit)
             ->get(); // executing the query
```

This will output a result like this:

```
{
    "id": 844,
    "user_id": 221,
    "content": "Das ist mein aller erster Post :) ",
    "created_at": "2019-07-01 09:09:00",
    "updated_at": "2019-07-01 09:09:00",
    "likes_count": 1,
    "comments": {
      {
        'username' : 'test',
        'comment' : "Das ist der zweite Kommentar",
        'created_at': 12312312
      },
      {
        'username' : 'test',
        'comment' : "Das ist der dritte :)",
        'created_at': 12312312
      }
    }
}
```

Check in the docs the topics related to this solution:

- [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)
- [Counting Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

Comment: If you do want to use Eloquent I believe it is not enabled by default in Lumen.  To use it you need to uncomment the $app->withEloquent() call in your bootstrap/app.php file.

Comment: @skribe yep, you are absolutely right. Totally missed that. Nice catch.